# Insert specified number of columns between two named columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I am trying to use VBA to insert a set number of columns between two preexisting and defined ones.

However, it keeps inserting the new columns to the left of the range. I want to insert the columns within the range.

Here's my VBA code to provide some context:

```
Sub InsertNewColummnbetween()
Range(Range("Data_FirstColumn").Offset(, 1), Range("Data_Net").Offset(,2)).EntireColumn.

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To Range("Assumptions!B26").Value
    Columns(1).INSERT
Next i
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

What is wrong with my commands?

Answer (score 1):

Some of this may depend on whether you have a worksheet with data, or if you defined a ListObject.

In your code, I'd avoid the loop, since you only want to insert 2 columns once.

```
Sub InsertNewColumn()
  Dim objSheet as Worksheet
  Set objSheet = ActiveWorksheet
  With objSheet
        .Columns(2).Insert shift:=xlRight
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The Insert method only allows for the Range to be shifted down or to the right (in this case, to the right.)  For this reason, you'll need to specify the range of the Column that you want to end up just to the right of your inserted columns.  See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195769%28v=office.11%29.aspx) for more info on Insert.